# Convert old MS-DOS text document with IBM/EPSON-codes to "modern" format like ODT/PDF/DOC/etc

Tags: text-editing

I have an electronic book. Format of this book is plain text with control codes for IBM/EPSON matrix printers. How can I convert this document to "modern" format (like ODT/PDF/DOC/any other)?

Comment: I guess we'll need a snippet to understand what codes you're talking about.

Comment: What the hell is this being downvoted for ._.

Answer (score 0):

If it is indeed plain text with Epson printer codes, you could download DOSPrinter: http://www.dosprinter.net.
And let it print the file to a RTF or PDF file.